# How do I create a pager for a view that shows the alphabet instead of numbers?

Tags: xpages

I have a need to have an alphabetical pager for a view.  I didn't see any of the samples or the custom pager that addresses this.  I would think that this would be a pretty common thing.

MJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you really mean by an "alphabetical pager", but I assume you might be looking for some kind of alphabetical navigator like we have it in the personal NAB inside the Notes client, right?

If so you're not really looking for a pager but for an alphabetical view filter. Here's one way to get there:

- create a panel, give it a distinctive ID like "viewContainer" or
  something. Put your view panel into the panel; of course the view's main sorting order must be alphabetical
- create a 2nd panel above "viewContainer", no ID necessary here
- put a repeat inside this new panel and bind it to a new JavaScript array, like that:

  new Array("a", "b", "c", ... , "x", "y", "z");
- enter a collection name for the repeat, like "letter"
- put a link control inside the repeat. The link's label will be
  computed to the repeat's collection name, i.e. "letter".
- assign an onclick event to the link setting a sessionScope variable to the current collection name's value, like that:

  sessionScope.filter = letter;
- set the event's refresh mode to partial so that it refreshes your viewContainer panel
- highlight your view control inside the viewContainer. In its data properties look for the property field labelled "Filter by column value" and make it computed. Enter this code:

  sessionScope.filter;

That's it.

**Edit:** 
of course you can build the repeat's datasource array dynamically from the view itself. So, instead of building that static a-to-z array you could also use something like this:

```
@Unique(@Left(@DbColumn(@DbName(), "yourLookupView", viewColNumber), 1));
```

That should return an array only containing those letters that really are in your view.

Also you could another static link control outside the repeat resetting the filter to show all entries. It would be built like the repeated link with the onclick event calling this code:

```
sessionScope.filter=null;
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this: make a view categorized by formula `@Left( value; 1)`. Then render result of @DbColumn as pager by repeat or some ExtLib component (links list, navigator, menu). Each link will either limit shown view to "single category" or jumps to "starts with" character.